# 例外が投げられる条件

Tags: php

```
public function delete($id,$password){

    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT password FROM post_3 WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->bindValue(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $db_password = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    var_dump($db_password);

    if(!password_verify($password,$db_password)){
        throw new Exception('パスワードが違います');
    }

    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM post_3 WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->bindValue(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

}
```

上記コードは簡易な掲示板のフォームより送信されたデータを元にデータベースの値を削除するメソッドなのですが、上記コードでは、try,catch文にて、データベース接続処理を書いていません。try,catch文内ではないのですが、「throw new Exception('パスワードが違います');」
と例外を投げることはできるのでしょうか？

実際に、エラーを出す為、

```
if(!password_verify($password,$db_password)){
    throw new Exception('パスワードが違います');
}
```

ここの部分でfalseとなるように、間違ったパスワードを掲示板のフォームより入力し、動かしてみましたら、以下のように表示されました。

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: パスワードが違います in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\object_bbs.php\bbs_class1.php:100 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\object_bbs.php\delete1.php(25): Bbs->delete(15, '1111111111') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\object_bbs.php\bbs_class1.php on line 100
```

一応、「パスワードが違います」と例外を投げた際に記載した文字列が表示されています。
これは、例外処理がなされた、ということなのでしょうか？

自分としましては、try,catch文内の、catchが出来なければ、例外を投げても受け取れないのではないのかなと思ったもので、疑問に思い質問させて貰いました。
ご回答、頂けましたら幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 質問の中のプログラムには、どこにも”catch”の文字が見当たりません。try-catch構文を使っているプログラムを質問に追加してください。（当然ですが、catch文が無いプログラムで例外が起きたら、「キャッチされなかった例外」(Uncaught Exception)が起こります。

Comment: 実は、関数の中身のデータベース処理を含め大枠の部分を、try,catch文で囲ってみたのですが、```if(!password_verify($password,$db_password)){
    throw new Exception('パスワードが違います');
}```ここの部分で、「false」となると、同じエラー内容が表示されるんですよね...「(Uncaught Exception)」といったエラーは表示されていない状況です。

Comment: 質問の本質とは外れるかもしれませんが、@774RR さんも書いている様に「パスワードの入力間違え」は想定し得るユーザー操作なので、`try-catch`より`if-else`で適切なエラー画面なりをユーザーに見せた方が親切な気もします。

Comment: ＞、try-catchよりif-elseで適切なエラー画面なりをユーザーに見せた方が親切な気もします
アドバイス頂きまして、ありがとうございます。
@774RRさんにも教えて頂きましたので、取り敢えずは、「delete」関数を呼び出す側で、```if-else```などの処理で、エラーメッセージの出力処理を検討してみたいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自分で `catch` を書かない場合、処理系ランタイムライブラリ中にある `catch` が例外を捕捉して実行エラーの表示となります。提示 [php](/questions/tagged/php) コードを `apache httpd` で実行したなら、閲覧者には `500 Internal Server Error` になる（のかな？）

Q1. 自分で `catch` を書かずに `throw` してよいか？
A1. 良いです。

Q2. このとき `catch` されるのか？
A2. 処理系ランタイムライブラリが `catch` します。その結果は実行エラーになりますが、それがあなたの期待した動作かどうかは別問題。

Q3. 実行エラーにならないよう大域の `try` / `catch` を書くべきか
A3. いいえ。そんなことするとデバッグできなくなります。最小限の例外種類を最小限の範囲で `try` / `catch` し、自分で処理できない例外は上位にスルーしてください。

---

えっと [php](/questions/tagged/php) だから勝手に web application であると思っていましたが httpd 関係なく php コンソールアプリケーションでしょうか？　まあどっちでも大差はないのすが

`try` / `catch` と `throw` は「責任の分担」に使います。そして `catch` すべきは「自分が対処できるもののみ」であると覚えてください。

提示 `delete` は自分の責任として
- パスワードが違っていたら例外を投げる
ところまでを担当しています。

パスワード違い例外発生時に具体的にどうすべきかは `delete` を呼ぶ側の責任である（ように現在設計されています）。そのため `catch` は `delete` を呼ぶ側に書きます。

ユーザーがパスワードを誤って入力することは普通にありうる操作なので、上記仕様のまま行くなら `delete` を呼ぶ側に `try` / `catch` を置いて、生成される `HTML` 上に「パスワードが違います」と出力するなど対処が必要です（対処しないと 500) 。

---

例外をどう使うかはプログラミング言語によって、プログラムの仕様を策定する人によって、違いがありますのでこの場で解説すると本が１冊書けちゃいます。

業務例外　と　システム例外　で検索してみてください。

業務例外は発生すべくして発生するので `catch` して対処すべき
- ユーザーがパスワードを誤って入力することは普通にあり得る
- ユーザが複数タブ開いて削除操作をしたら、多重に記事削除しようとすることは普通にあり得る

システム例外とは端的にはプログラムのバグのことです。バグっていることが閲覧者に通知されても閲覧者は何もできないので、開発者がきっちりデバッグする必要があります。こういうのはデバッグの助けになるようエラーログを残したい。ランタイムライブラリの提供しているデフォルト例外ハンドラはエラーログを出力するので `catch` しないことだけで事足ります。
- 配列の添え字があふれた
- SQL 文に文法エラーがある
- データベースに接続できない
- データーベース操作がタイムアウトした

繰り返しますが、必要な個所に必要な種類の `catch` を最小限に書くようにしてください。そうするだけでデバッグがとても楽になります。開発中の未完成なプログラムがログ付きでエラー終了するのはとても正しいことですから（実用に供するまでには十分デバッグしてくださいね）

Comment: ご回答いただき、ありがとうございます。
＞Q3. 実行エラーにならないよう大域の try / catch を書くべきか
この点についてなのですが、投げた例外を「catch」で補足し、画面に表示させた場合でも、例外が発生したとみなされ、処理は中断されないのでしょうか？
実は、今回の場合ですと、パスワード認証の部分でして、パスワードが違った場合は、利用者には、画面上に「パスワードが違います。」との表示を出させたいと思っているんですよね...
何か良い方法があれば、教えて頂けませんでしょうか...?

Comment: ご丁寧に、教えて頂きありがとうございます。PHPを勉強しているのですが、責任の分担の部分など、大変勉強になりました。さらには、「業務例外」「システム例外」のことなど、知らなかった為、教えて頂き、勉強になりました。
実は、現在オブジェクト指向の勉強としまして、簡易な掲示板を作成しているのですが、オブジェクト指向で、作るにしてもどのようなメリットが存在するか未だ理解できていない為、取り敢えず、クラスの中に関数を作って、呼び出す、といったことを目的としていた為、特段それ以外のことは考えていなかったんですよね...一度、インスタンスを生成したファイル（呼び出す側）で、「try,catch」文を組み込み、ユーザーが、間違ってパスワードを入力した場合のメッセージの出力処理を考えてみたいと思います。